# List only files for current user

Tags: linux, command-line, ls

How can I limit `ls` to only show files where I am the owner?

I might be able to string together something using `find` along with `ls`, but I'm looking for an `ls` only solution.

Comment: See if this works>>>>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/346284/how-to-list-files-by-file-owner-in-unix-command

Answer (score 0):

That's it basically

ls - l | grep $USER

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -group {group-name} -name {file-name}
find . -user {user-name} -iname "*.txt"
find . -user {user-name} -exec ls -l {} \;
ls -l | grep " {user-name} "
```

And think there is no way to do this just with `ls` command `man ls`

Comment: this also will work :) `ls -ltr | awk '/ {user-name} / {print $0}'`